# Does the Christian bible forbid marriage out of Christianity?

Tags: christianity, bible

Does the bible, specifically say a Christian can not marry someone who is not Christian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Christian text in the bible forbids Christians from marrying non-Christians. (Some Christian 'old testament' texts do forbid or discourage Israelites from marrying non-Israelites.)

Paul, in 1 Corinthians 7.12-16, addresses a circumstance in which a Christian is already married to a non-Christian: don't seek out a divorce, the Christian spouse uplifts his/her non-Christian family.

However, Paul in 2 Corinthians 6.14 forbids becoming 'partners' with non-Christians, though it is a little unclear how far this extends (the immediate context is of not compromising Christian beliefs by mixing with non-Christian beliefs).